# Getting nx format:write uncommitted failed without output and eslint --fix failed without output error when I do git commit

Tags: reactjs, eslint, prettier

Getting nx format:write --uncommitted failed and eslint --fix failed without output error when I try to do git commit

When I try to do git commit it is showing as below

> Running tasks for staged files...

> .lintstagedrc.json 1 file $schema no files [SKIPPED]

> {apps, libs}/**/*. {ts, tsx, js, jsx) - 1 file * eslint-fix [KILLED]

> .(ts, tsx, js, jsx, json, nd, arc) 1 file nx format:write -uncommitted [SIGSEGV] Skipped because of errors from tasks. [SKIPPED]

I

✓ Reverting to original state because of errors...

✓ Cleaning up temporary files...

*nx format:write -uncommitted failed without output (SIGSEGV).

- eslint --fix failed without output

Comment: The "eslint-fix KILLED" message points to an ESLint problem. It's not a Git issue (at least not until you fix the eslint issue).